# MySQL Queries Running At Different Speeds

Tags: mysql

I have a web system that i am migrating over to aws and most areas seem to be fine. There is one specific click on the web system that is extremely slow on aws side. I was able to locate the mysql query that gets executed in order to compare it to the old system and everything is the same, even the indexes. The query is below

```
select distinct cf_1274 from vtiger_cf_1274 
inner join vtiger_role2picklist on vtiger_role2picklist.picklistvalueid = vtiger_cf_1274.picklist_valueid 
where roleid in ("H3","H4","H5","H51","H50","H49","H2") and picklistid in (select picklistid from vtiger_cf_1274) 
order by sortid asc
```

The only difference i can see between the two is that the old mysql server version is 5.0.95 and the newer version is 5.6.X

I was also able to run an explain on both and this is where i saw differences. The newer system had a few "Using Join Buffer (Block Nested Loop)" on the extra column in the explain query where as the old one did not. Im assuming this must be the issue, but im not sure how to approach it.

Comment: You must have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: why is `and picklistid in (select picklistid from vtiger_cf_1274)` needed? isn't it always true?

Comment: I ended up turning off block nested loops as it was one of the parameters in RDS parameter group. This solved the speed issue. The issue was that there are diffferent default values set in MySQL server 5.0.X vs 5.6.X

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not qualify what fields are coming from what table, at a minimum, you should even apply ALIAS to the query as I started here.

You are joining to the picklist table with the vtiger_cf_1274 table by the picklist value, so why not do a join on BOTH picklist value AND picklist ID.  This way, you can get rid of the IN ( select ) qualifier.

Also, I that becomes the new join criteria, I would have your role picklist table indexed on the (picklistvalueid, picklistid) to optimize the criteria..

Showing sample data context of these tables would help confirm / simplify / resolve your query.

```
select distinct 
      cf_1274 
   from 
      vtiger_cf_1274 VT
         inner join vtiger_role2picklist PL
            on VT.picklist_valueid = PL.picklistvalueid 
           AND VT.picklistid = PL.picklistID ???
   where 
          roleid in ("H3","H4","H5","H51","H50","H49","H2") 
   order by 
      sortid asc
```